# What does the following pseudocode mean?

Tags: pseudocode

I'm interested in what the following means

```
T(i) = 1+max{T(j) if a[j] < a[i]: 1 < j < i-1}
```

I am interpreting it as the function T(i) equals the maximum of T(j) only if a[j] is smaller than a[i] and j is bigger than 1 but smaller than i-1

Comment: What's the context? The code you posted could be interpreted as "Assign to subscript `i` of `T` _or_ "Define function `T` of `i`".

Comment: Recursive relation for Longest Increasing Subsequence (LIS). Part of Dynamic Programming problem solving

Answer (score 0):

I believe what it means is very similar to what you interpreted, except for a small change.

I would read it as:
*T(i) is equal to 1 plus the maximum of T(j) if a[j] > a[i], where 1 is less then j which is less than i-1.*

It basically is similar to what you said, but I wanted to point out that the ":" probably signifies "where".